# How to resend confirmation email in Django from a React front end, using allauth and rest-auth

Tags: django, django-allauth, email-validation

I'm using Django 2.0.10 with rest framework, rest-auth and allauth, with a React front end. Rest-auth provides login and logout functionality using JWT token authentication, but I can't work out how to allow the user to request a resend of the verification email.

I want a user to be able to log in and press a button saying "Resend confirmation email". If for example they accidentally deleted the email, they need to be able to request another.

I've seen posts suggesting that you can use send_email_confirmation from allauth, but this expects a CSRF token which would be generated by a template. I tried [following the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#id1) to excempt from csrf, but it doesn't make any different. I also tried setting authentication_classes = () [as suggested here](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/164). Here's my code:

settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

urls.py

```
from users.views import EmailConfirmation

urlpatterns = [
...
url(r'^/sendconfirmationemail/', EmailConfirmation.as_view(), name='send-email-confirmation')
]
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class EmailConfirmation(APIView):
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    authentication_classes = ()

    def post(self):
        send_email_confirmation(user=self.request.user)
```

When I post to the endpoint '/api/v1/rest-auth/sendconfirmationemail/', I get an error Forbidden:

```
<p>You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.</p>
<p>If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for &#39;same-origin&#39; requests.</p>
```

Edit: I have also tried to add the CSRF token to my request following tutorials [like this one](https://www.techiediaries.com/django-react-forms-csrf-axios/). But I have the same problem. Here's what I've tried:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            //var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
```

And then I construct my request to use fetch API like this:

```
curl 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/rest-auth/sendconfirmationemail/' -H 'Authorization: Token 55c8da5de68b657cf9dafd820a7f02f997fa3d64' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:3000' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:3000/account' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'X-CSRFToken: YOHB6RXqpZMFIXKT31T9tAjaUsH0w3eIjaaCvbgAqmP64SWeVNd3Sz3g8nZUEmVS' --data-binary 'csrfmiddlewaretoken=YOHB6RXqpZMFIXKT31T9tAjaUsH0w3eIjaaCvbgAqmP64SWeVNd3Sz3g8nZUEmVS' --compressed
```

When I look at working examples from Django templates, I see that the csrfmiddlewaretoken value sent with the form data is not the same as the X-CSRFToken sent in the header - I think the value supplied by Django templates is salted and this might make a difference. But no instructions I can find tell me how to get the right value? Or do I have my fetch request in the wrong form somehow?

If I use this form in my React page:

```
<form action="api/v1/sendconfirmationemail" method="post">
<Input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"  value={this.getCookie('csrftoken')} />
<button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

When I submit it, I get an error "Method Not Allowed (POST): /api/v1/sendconfirmationemail". The cURL from this request is:

```
curl 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sendconfirmationemail' -H 'Cookie: csrftoken=YOHB6RXqpZMFIXKT31T9tAjaUsH0w3eIjaaCvbgAqmP64SWeVNd3Sz3g8nZUEmVS; sessionid=uslpdgd5npa6wyk2oqpwkhj79xaen7nw' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:3000' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:3000/account' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data 'csrfmiddlewaretoken=YOHB6RXqpZMFIXKT31T9tAjaUsH0w3eIjaaCvbgAqmP64SWeVNd3Sz3g8nZUEmVS' --compressed
```

Any idea how I can request an email resend from the React frontend?

Comment: Possible duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709347/django-csrf-exempt-not-working-in-class-view

Comment: I don't think this is the same issue as I am using token authentication. That question uses oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication.

Comment: Either case you are not calling the method_decator on a method. It should be on top of the method. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class

Comment: I tried putting @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def post(self, request): this also did not work.

Comment: The more I think about it, you need to have csrf_token for login, since you are using react you probably need to pass the csrf_token to the header on your own. Here is the documents on the Jquery code that will pass the cookie https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#ajax

Comment: But, CSRF token is not used for login, or any other part of the rest api like get user details. Why would I need it here?

Comment: Login is based off Django's login, not rest api. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication

Comment: Honestly I don't understand why the CSRF is needed here when it's not needed for rest auth, but I have tried to set the CSRF cookie and can't make it work. I've followed the instructions you linked to find the 'X-CSRFToken' and send it with the header. but I think I also need to get the csrfmiddlewaretoken and include it in a hidden input on the page, and this isn't the same thing is it? It's been salted? I cannot find any instructions that work!

Comment: I'm puzzled now I will try to figure out a solution for you. I'll get back to you if I get anything.

Comment: I think I've finally worked it out - the CSRF error is shown when the URL is wrong, so your API call is not pointing at a valid Rest Framework URL.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think part of my trouble was that the server seems to show the `Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.) error` if the fetch request has the incorrect URL and is therefore not pointing at a valid rest-framework URL. This had me chasing after CSRF issues instead of double checking my URL.

I hope this will help somebody else. Here's my working code:

users/views.py

```
from allauth.account.signals import email_confirmed
from django.dispatch import receiver
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

from allauth.account.utils import send_email_confirmation
from rest_framework.views import APIView

from . import models
from . import serializers

from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response

class UserListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)

# when the email is confirmed, set a field on the user
# so the UI can check whether to show the "Resend confirmation email" button
@receiver(email_confirmed)
def email_confirmed_(request, email_address, **kwargs):
    user = email_address.user
    user.email_verified = True

    user.save()

# request a new confirmation email
class EmailConfirmation(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated] 

    def post(self, request):
        if request.user.email_verified:
            return Response({'message': 'Email already verified'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        send_email_confirmation(request, request.user)
        return Response({'message': 'Email confirmation sent'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

api/urls.py

```
from users.views import EmailConfirmation

urlpatterns = [
...
    path('sendconfirmationemail/', EmailConfirmation.as_view(), name='send-email-confirmation')
]
```

I'm sending a POST request using JavaScript fetch(), with the authentication token in the header like this:

```
-H 'Authorization: Token 98254e6004e4a28b9d8cf61e7a7a9ee2fc61009a'
```